# Google OAuth 2 works only from localhost

Tags: google-oauth

I'm trying to set up google sign-in on a web server with oauth2. Everything works perfectly when I try it from localhost:8000, but if I try it from my_ip_address:8000 I get the following error when I try to sign in:

```
400. That’s an error.
The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

My Javascript origins on the developer console are

```
http://<my_ip_address>:8000
http://localhost:8000
```

And my redirect uris are

```
http://localhost:8000
http://localhost:8000/*
```

IP addresses without any domain name are not allowed in the redirect URI section for some reason, so I can't add the server IP there.

If you happen to think this is more of an issue with apache than google, please let me know, but the only thing that changes when the IP is used rather than localhost is the link in the sign-in window.

Comment: You need to use a domain name with Google, not an IP address.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Ah, I see. I'm sure that public ip addresses will be allowed for javascript origins about the same time they are allowed for redirect uris. Thanks.